# About ergodic stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, ergodic

$x_t=2.1+0.73x_{t-1}+ε_t$

$ε_t \sim iid(0,σ_ε^2)$

Given the stochastic process with deep Gaussian process above, is x_t an ergodic stochastic process? If possible, I would like to know the reason.

Comment: Because this process is defined clearly and mathematically, you should be able to apply a definition of "ergodic."  What does that tell you?

Comment: So, as it is independent and identically distributed, is it ergodic?

Comment: Your comment refers to $(\varepsilon_t).$  I thought your question was about $(x_t)$?  Clearly $x_t$ and $x_{t-1}$ are never independent for any $t.$  You need to apply a suitable definition of *ergodic.*

Comment: |0.73|<1, so it means stationary? Plus ε_t is iid, so it can be said x_t is ergodic?